# get a widgets dc in wxpython

Tags: wxpython

im looking for a way to get a widget such as a panels device context if that is the right word. i want to get the bitmap of the panel with all its child widgets so i can manipulate it in a paint dc for fade in fade out animations of panels. is this possible and if so whats the code? i was hoping for something like this.. wx.Panel.GetDCMap()
which will return a bitmap of what is going to be painted to the screen so i can fade it. also this will need to grab the bitmap of what a widget will look like even if its hidden. else i could just use widget.GetScreenRect() then blit it to a buffer.. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice question! I didn't think it would work, but I tried this and it did:

```
def window_to_bitmap(window):
    width, height = window.GetSize()
    bitmap = wx.EmptyBitmap(width, height)
    wdc = wx.WindowDC(window)
    mdc = wx.MemoryDC(bitmap)
    mdc.Blit(0, 0, width, height, wdc, 0, 0)
    return bitmap
```

Doesn't work if the window is hidden.

Moving the window far off screen sort of works, the client area is shown but the window decorations are not shown.

Calling `SetTransparent(0)` first has a similar effect as moving the window off screen.

Above tests done on 64-bit Windows 7.

If you only need the client area, you could do one of the above methods and tweak the function to create a bitmap with the client area only, like so:

```
def window_to_bitmap(window):
    width, height = window.GetClientSize()
    bitmap = wx.EmptyBitmap(width, height)
    wdc = wx.ClientDC(window)
    mdc = wx.MemoryDC(bitmap)
    mdc.Blit(0, 0, width, height, wdc, 0, 0)
    return bitmap
```

Comment: you..... are a genius :) i knew about memoryDC and paintDC and screendc etc etc but havent heard of that windowDC before. extremly usefull thank you man :) you've been a huge help, i was busy remaking widgets just to get a hold of the dc lol